# Using DTO vs @InitBinder method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, dto

If we have complex models in Spring MVC and want to bind form fields to them we could either use a DTO object with simple attributes (matching those on the html form) and then build the real model object from data in that DTO; or we can use `@InitBinder` methods that not only enable us to bind (convert) form fields to complex objects but also allow us to set custom validators and so on.

It seems to me that use of DTOs is discouraged:

> The most misused pattern in the Java Enterprise community is the DTO.
>   DTO was clearly defined as a solution for a distribution problem. DTO
>   was meant to be a coarse-grained data container which efficiently
>   transports data between processes (tiers). [~ Adam Bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_deal_with_j2ee)

> This pattern is often incorrectly used outside of remote interfaces.
>   This has triggered a response from its author where he reiterates
>   that the whole purpose of DTOs is to shift data in expensive remote
>   calls. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

So should we always use `@InitBinder`s?